# PHP custom session handler - database connection becoming NULL

Tags: php

I debugged and searched for quite a while and I can't figure out what is happening. This is my first time doing a `custom session handler`, so I'm afraid I'm overlooking something painfully obvious. I want to implement a custom session handler so I can store additional information with the sessions and be able to temporarily disable access to protected areas of the site for certain groups of users.

My login page (which was working fine with basic file-based php sessions), includes a php file with a lot of functions including the session handler functions and my error handler. That included file includes a third file that does the database connection. The connection is made using `mysqli_connect()` and the resulting link is stored in a variable, `$dbc`. That same connection is used throughout the site for logging errors, loading/editing site content, etc. I decided to use the same database connection, since it is used already on every page and my session handler will need to be used on almost every page as well. Nowhere in my code do I manually close the database connection, but I think perhaps it is automatically closing somehow.

My functions access the database connection ($dbc) with a global statement. Ex:

```
function sess_write($id, $data)
{
    global $dbc;
    ...
```

My `open`, `read`, and `write` functions are supposed to use the variable in this manner. I checked the database connection variable in the open and read functions and it is non-null as expected, but in my write function it suddenly shows up as null. Is PHP doing something between read and write that could potentially be closing that connection? I created a test variable in the same included file that creates the database connection, and used the same `global $test;` statement in the write function, and that variable appears just fine, so I'm guessing it has something to do with the database being closed. I tried using a second variable to store the database connection (to only be used by the session handler) and that didn't work either. Any ideas? Am I just being dumb as usual?

Comment: After posting this, I found a link in the Related posts that may be the answer I'm looking for. This is quoted:

"As of PHP 5.0.5 the write and close handlers are called after object destruction and therefore cannot use objects or throw exceptions."

Now I'm guessing that the mysqli_connect function is actually creating an object that is being destroyed before it can be used in the write function. How can I make that connection accessible to the write function? I'm continuing to read on the subject, sorry for posting too soon.

Comment: The solution I have come across is to use the object-based form of the database connection and have a destructor that recreates the connection. But that seems odd to have the connection destroyed and recreated. Is there any other way to pass the database connection to the write function as I  am using it? Or is this class solution what I should do? I'm guessing I can't add arguments to the write function, since what is passed to those functions is handled internally by php. The global variables are being passed, but the variable I'm using is a reference to an object.

Comment: And since that object has been destroyed, it explains why a text variable worked fine but the $dbc variable didn't. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: And is there any point to having anything in the write and close functions, when I can just have the object destructor call a  function that writes the session to the database. I wasn't really planning on closing the connection - is there any reason I would want to do that explicitly?

Comment: I'm also not sure why this write function is even executing at all. All that should be happening in the login page is giving the session name and use session_start(). I thought the write function shouldn't be called unless the session data has been altered by assigning something to the $_SESSION variables or using session_regenerate_id(). Is it because of the session name that the write function is being called? I thought that specifying the name of the session only changed the name of the cookie essentially.

Answer (score 0):

Per your note, that is correct -- objects will be disposed of before write and close.  The traditional workaround for this is to use the [register_shutdown_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).  PHP 5.4 now has [an interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php) you can use to write a session handler class that simplifies this process.  If you implement the interface in a session class, when you pass it to  session_set_save_handler() it defaults to setting things up to register the shutdown call for you.